# Getting data from REST API (JSON), extract variables and upload those to database using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json, database

I'm working with a REST API, first time doing this and I have a working code but it's long and just looks messy to me. I just know there's a better and faster way to do it.

```
try {
$LOCATIONS = new \Picqer\Financials\Exact\ItemWarehouse($connection);
$LOCATIONS_GET = $LOCATIONS->get();
foreach($LOCATIONS_GET as $LOCATIONS){
   $locationID = $LOCATIONS->ID;
   $locationDefaultStorageLocationCode = $LOCATIONS->DefaultStorageLocationCode;
   $locationDefaultStorageLocatoinDescription = $LOCATIONS->DefaultStorageLocationDescription;
   $locationWarehouseCode = $LOCATIONS->WarehouseCode;
   $locationDefaultStorageLocation = $LOCATIONS->DefaultStorageLocation;
   $locationLocatieType = 0; //Locatie type

  $LOCATIONS_CHECK = $conn->query("SELECT ID FROM data_exact_locations WHERE ID='$locationID' LIMIT 1");
  if($LOCATIONS_CHECK->num_rows == 0){
    $LOCATIONS_SQL = "INSERT INTO data_exact_locations (ID, Code, Omschrijving, Magazijn, Standaardlocatie, Locatie_type)
    VALUES ('$locationID','$locationDefaultStorageLocationCode','$locationDefaultStorageLocatoinDescription', '$locationWarehouseCode', '$locationDefaultStorageLocation')";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $LOCATIONS_SQL)){
      echo "Worked! <BR>";
    } else{
      echo ("Try again! <BR>" . mysqli_error($conn));
    }
  } else {
    echo ("Already in database! <BR>");
  }
}
} catch (\Exception $e) {
echo get_class($e) . ' : ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

This is what the code looks like, but this is a short version. There are also instances where I need to get something like 30 variables out of the JSON file, and upload those to a database.

Another example from the same code:

```
try {
$CRM = new \Picqer\Financials\Exact\Account($connection);
$CRM_GET = $CRM->filter("IsSupplier eq true");
foreach($CRM_GET as $CRM){
     $crmID = $CRM->ID;
     $crmCode = $CRM->Code;
     $crmSearchCode =$CRM->SearchCode;
     $crmName = $CRM->Name;
     $crmAddressLine1 = $CRM->AddressLine1;
     $crmAddressline2 = $CRM->AddressLine2;
     $crmAddressline3 = $CRM->AddressLine3;
     $crmVatNumber = $CRM->VATNumber;
     $crmCountry = $CRM->Country;
     $crmCity = $CRM->City;
     $crmPostcode = $CRM->Postcode;
     $crmState = $CRM->State;
     $crmRemarks = $CRM->Remarks;

 $CRM_CHECK = $conn->query("SELECT ID FROM data_exact_crm WHERE ID='$crmID' LIMIT 1");
 if($CRM_CHECK->num_rows == 0){
   $CRM_SQL = "INSERT INTO data_exact_crm (ID, Code, SearchCode, Name, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, AddressLine3, VATNumber, CountryDescription, City, PostCode, StateDescription, Remarks)
   VALUES ('$crmID','$crmCode','$crmSearchCode','$crmName','$crmAddressLine1','$crmAddressline2','$crmAddressline3','$crmVatNumber','$crmCountry','$crmCity','$crmPostcode','$crmState','$crmRemarks')";
   if (mysqli_query($conn, $CRM_SQL)){
     echo "Worked! <BR>";
   } else{
     echo ("Try Again! <BR>" . mysqli_error($conn));
   }
 } else {
   echo ("Already in database! <BR>");
 }
 }
  } catch (\Exception $e) {
  echo get_class($e) . ' : ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but does this code work? The value parameters are string representations of your variable name and I'm not sure this works in PHP (or in a lot of languages)

Comment: Yeah it works, i just thought it was really inefficient

Comment: _this is a short version_ - does it mean you've removed anything from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDO has a great feature for you, [it can accept an array with parameters for `execute()`](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#prepared). It means you won't have to extract separate variables anymore.

So just use PDO instead of mysqli and your code will become just two lines

```
$CRM_GET = $CRM->filter("IsSupplier eq true");
$stmt = "INSERT IGNORE INTO data_exact_crm (ID, Code, SearchCode, Name, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, AddressLine3, VATNumber, CountryDescription, City, PostCode, StateDescription, Remarks)
   VALUES (:ID,:Code, :SearchCode,:Name,:AddressLine1,:Addressline2,:Addressline3,:VatNumber,:Country,:City,:Postcode,:State,:Remarks)";
foreach($CRM_GET as $CRM) {
    $stmt->execute((array)$CRM);
}
```

Notice that I am using quite a few tricks here:

- an object is converted to an array for PDO
- prepare is called only once which makes your queries executed faster (you can read on that from my article I linked above)
- assuming ID is a primary key, there is no need to run a select query. Just add a keyword IGNORE to the INSERT statement
- your error handling code is overkill. if you leave an exception alone, **it will tell you exactly the same information you are echoing manually**. So get rid of try/catch as well
- of course such output as Worked! or Try again after each query execution is not informative ans should be removed as well

Comment: "So just use PDO instead of mysqli"

Comment: @Your_Common_Sense Sorry that was a dumb question i forgot to make a `$pdoconn`. But i keep running into trouble trying to use pdo. It seems like PDO can't get the data from $CRM.   Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\testOmgeving\INVENTORY_LOCATIONS_TEST.php on line 103

Recoverable fatal error: Object of class Picqer\Financials\Exact\Connection could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\testOmgeving\INVENTORY_LOCATIONS_TEST.php on line 103

Comment: In case $CRM contains any extra variables, they must be unset processing. just add unset($CRM['foo'],$CRM['bar'],...); before execute

Comment: Well, if $CRM is an object with a magical getter, there is no way to avoid a manual assignment.